# Cannot import GeoJSON into Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I'm trying to load in a GeoJSON file to an OpenLayers web app and can't for the life of me work out why this won't work. I have the following js code:

```
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
var base_layer = new ol.layer.Group({
  'title': 'Base maps',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      title: 'OSM Data',
      type: 'base',
      visible: true,
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ]
});

var vector_overlays = new ol.layer.Group({
  'title': 'Vector Overlays',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      title: 'Soum boundaries',
      visible: true,
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        url: 'geofiles/test.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
      })
    })
  ]
});

var map = new Map({
  layers: [base_layer, vector_overlays],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [102.376126,48.031532],
    zoom: 6
  })
});
```

And I keep getting the following error relating to the GeoJSON:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

With the GeoJSON having the following structure (which jsonlint said was a valid GeoJSON):

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "soums",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 1104, "OBJECTID": 25, "AREA_M2": 156387542.76619899, "LENGTH_M": 49278.986543539999, "TYPE": 3, "NAME": "Bagaxangai", "NAME_L1": "??????????", "PARENT_ID": 11, "UNIT_STATU": 2, "SHAPE_AREA": 0.01862, "SHAPE_LEN": 0.54868 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 107.488336568318374, 47.436899185450194 ], [ 107.489774709328984, 47.434026718450731 ], [ 107.495859151369757, 47.424669266453314 ], [ 107.499013906391355, 47.419637680454585 ], [ 107.500501638401317, 47.417390823455229 ], [ 107.500936513403644, 47.41711235045544 ], [ 107.505739217436854, 47.409326553457433 ], [ 107.509119039460501, 47.40374183745881 ], [ 107.516798024514614, 47.39104652446202 ], [ 107.519193654531065, 47.387380600463018 ], [ 107.528028493593624, 47.373025894466807 ], [ 107.528253560595189, 47.372671127466873 ], [ 107.529497152604023, 47.37064552346741 ], [ 107.529825216606397, 47.370115280467537 ], [ 107.530122762608514, 47.369634628467644 ], [ 107.53040505061054, 47.369176865467786 ], [ 107.541345601688874, 47.351480484472447 ], [ 107.551515584762541, 47.33506202747683 ], [ 107.552148824767386, 47.333909988477139 ], [ 107.552873616772274, 47.332963943477417 ], [ 107.554182058780611, 47.331571579478023 ], [ 107.554227834781955, 47.33090782247799 ], [ 107.545320516743928, 47.328996658473685 ], [ 107.532812124690608, 47.32650184646765 ], [ 107.530157094679709, 47.325731277466389 ], [ 107.519140249633281, 47.323453903461136 ], [ 107.509058004591253, 47.32120323245644 ], [ 107.50864983158958, 47.321115494456251 ], [ 107.50836754358842, 47.321054459456093 ], [ 107.50619698157935, 47.320600510455115 ], [ 107.504934316574094, 47.320329666454512 ], [ 107.501577382560143, 47.319620132452954 ], [ 107.50076866655678, 47.319448471452539 ], [ 107.500165944554411, 47.319250107452284 ], [ 107.499048238549975, 47.318880081451738 ], [ 107.497632985544101, 47.318574905451086 ], [ 107.497129445542029, 47.318468094450893 ], [ 107.472394948440453, 47.313173294439565 ], [ 107.440416341310964, 47.306631088425306 ], [ 107.434911733288885, 47.305501938422907 ], [ 107.417737966220656, 47.301958084415411 ], [ 107.394849782080144, 47.332387924406603 ], [ 107.393877034074279, 47.333669662406223 ], [ 107.392713552066866, 47.335481644405839 ], [ 107.388719564042603, 47.340860367404282 ], [ 107.376668934970681, 47.356714249399715 ], [ 107.370676045934985, 47.364812851397481 ], [ 107.362928395889284, 47.375173569394597 ], [ 107.357919697859273, 47.382310867392746 ], [ 107.351121906820339, 47.390932083390197 ], [ 107.346796040794445, 47.397344589388624 ], [ 107.347578053794678, 47.399400711388992 ], [ 107.353464131796457, 47.414918900391712 ], [ 107.356546406795289, 47.424524307393213 ], [ 107.402032856952559, 47.441427231412383 ], [ 107.428442006072856, 47.432771683423468 ], [ 107.488336568318374, 47.436899185450194 ] ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

I've looked around at the other questions on Stack Overflow but haven't been able to locate any regarding an error this this, and I tried implementing solutions to more general json file with this error, but nothing so fa has worked. I have no idea what to do next!

[Link to GeoJSON file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LBIZkF9_t4XcxNsP4e6nbmo8Zi2xZfrl)

**UPDATE**

Based off the helpful suggestions below and noticing that the file geocodezip uploaded based off my GeoJSON worked, I think this is definitely a MIME type issue. I'm now getting:

> The script from
>   “http://localhost:1234/04d3cf9866d7a5d5ca27b8351f6969ac.js” was loaded
>   even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME
>   type.

I've been having a look to see how to get OpenLayers to work for GeoJSON mime types but haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: try opening the geojson url in the browser to make sure it is being served correctly (sometimes `.geojson` may need to be set up in MIME types)

Comment: Which version of OpenLayers are you using? Your GeoJSON looks fine and has no syntax error as I pasted it in [geojson.io](http://geojson.io). I would suggest you write your code in [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/pen/) and let us spot the problem more easily. You can add OpenLayers lib in JS section clicking on the "gear" icon.

Comment: I'm using OpenLayers 5.3.0 at the moment. Regarding codepen, looks very useful! I opened it up and copied the code in but it didn't flag anything up.

Answer (score 3):

When you define your `new ol.format.GeoJSON`,  set the `dataProjection` and `featureProjection` appropriately and use `ol.proj.fromLonLat` to set the `center` from `ESPG:4326` coordinates.

```
format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
})
```

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [base_layer, vector_overlays],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([102.376126, 48.031532]),
      zoom: 6
    })
  });
```

[proof of concept page](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_5.3.0_GeoJSON_SO20190927c.html)

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script>
  var base_layer = new ol.layer.Group({
    'title': 'Base maps',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'OSM Data',
        type: 'base',
        visible: true,
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ]
  });

  var vector_overlays = new ol.layer.Group({
    'title': 'Vector Overlays',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Vector({
        title: 'Soum boundaries',
        visible: true,
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          projection: 'EPSG:4326',
          url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/upkqh',
          format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
            dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
            featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
          })
        })
      })
    ]
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [base_layer, vector_overlays],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([102.376126, 48.031532]),
      zoom: 6
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your "myjson" url also works perfectly with the original all EPSG:4326 setup in the question.  A parsing error at the first character of the first line would suggest the locally hosted copy isn't being served as expected

Comment: I see what you mean: http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_5.3.0_GeoJSON_SO20190927_0.html (although I don't know about "perfectly", the tiles look stretched to me).

Comment: It's as perfect as you will get with reprojection https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/reprojection-wgs84.html

Comment: Running the code with your link resulted in the error disappearing, while running it with my geojson, even with dataProjection and featureProjection defined, still resulted in the error. So this implies that there must be something wrong with how I'm serving the geojson out

Comment: I've uploaded the GeoJSON file to my Google Drive for downloading in case it's something to do with the GeoJSON file for some reason

Comment: Did you see Mike's comment on your question regarding MIME types (and his first comment in response to this answer)?

Comment: I will investigate more into MIME types in the mean time

Comment: It does indeed to be a MIME type problem, I will edit my original question to explain

Comment: Configure your server to serve the geojson as `Content-Type: application/vnd.geo+json` (per this [link](https://sgillies.net/2014/05/22/the-geojson-media-type.html) (or upload it as .txt, which works for my server).

Answer (score 0):

For starters, check if something from this link will steer you in right direction.

[How to get GeoJSON into OpenLayers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50211597/how-to-get-geojson-into-openlayers/50212538#50212538)

If nothing here helps then try changing crs in geojson file. From this:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "soums",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
...
```

To this

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "soums",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": {"name":"EPSG:4326"} },
...
```

Comment: Ah, I'd already read up on that GeoJSON question before posting my own. Hadn't helped unfortunately :( I tried changing the EPSG in my file, but it didn't work either