# how to read features out of a geojson format

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I have the below posted geojson. I want to read the feature out of that geojson so i can do some processing on that feature.
please let me know how to read features out of a geojson format

**code**:

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [10.915212708803605, 50.70360315580079]}, 'properties': {'isRepresentative': 'y', 'hasPixelValueSatisfyThreshold': 'y'}}]}
```

Comment: You can look at that answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50211597/how-to-get-geojson-into-openlayers/50212538#50212538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This official example should help you, https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html

```
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';

const geojsonObject = {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [10.915212708803605, 50.70360315580079]}, 'properties': {'isRepresentative': 'y', 'hasPixelValueSatisfyThreshold': 'y'}}]};
const features = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject),
```